# Need help getting OneToMany association from ManyToOne

Tags: php, symfony, orm

Let me start off by saying I asked a similar question before and got it answered. I tried using those principles here but I'm stuck again am am not sure where to go from here.

I have a page where I list out all the 'products' along with their respected id's, price, and name. On this same page I want to get a description I created for each of them. Description is its own entity and has it's own controller.

In my `ProductController`, within my `indexAction`, I'm trying to get the description to appear here.

The problem is, I don't reference an id within `indexAction` (I use findAll). I have tried to loop through all products and reference using `$key` but I either get the most recent description entered in description or currently:

*Error: Call to a member function getDescriptions() on a non-object.*

EDIT: I should mention $prodEnt is null...

I didn't want to come here for help but I have no more thoughts on how to go about getting what I want.

Here is `ProductController` with `indexAction`:

```
namespace Pas\ShopTestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Pas\ShopTestBundle\Entity\Product;
use Pas\ShopTestBundle\Form\ProductType;

/**
 * Product controller.
 *
 * @Route("/product")
 */
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all Product entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="product")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('PasShopTestBundle:Product')->findAll();

        //$entities = $em->getRepository('PasShopTestBundle:Product')->find($id);
        //var_dump($entities);
        //dump($entities); die;

        if (!$entities) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Error Nothing in Entities.');
        } 
        else {
            //dump($entities); die;
            foreach ($entities as $key => $entity) {
                //dump($entities); die;
                //dump($entity); die;
                //dump($key); die; //needs to be 1
                //$entity = $em->getRepository('PasShopTestBundle:Product')->findAll($key);
                $prodEnt = $em->getRepository('PasShopTestBundle:Product')->find($key);
                //dump($entity); die;
                //dump($prodEnt); die;
                $descriptions = $prodEnt->getDescriptions();
                //dump($entity); die;
            }
            //dump($entities); die;
        }

        return array(
            'descriptions' => $descriptions,
            'entities' => $entities,
            'entity' => $entity,
        );
    }
```

Here is `indexAction`s Route twig file:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body -%}
    <h1>Product List</h1>

    <table class="records_list">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for entity in entities %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{{ path('product_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.id }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.price }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.quantity }}</td>

                {% for key, entity in descriptions %}

                    <pre>{{ dump(entity) }}</pre>

                   {# <pre>{{ dump(key) }}</pre> #}

                        <td>{{ entity.productDesciption }}</td>

                    <pre>{{ dump(entity.productDesciption) }}</pre>

                {% endfor %}

                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ path('product_cart', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">Add Product To Cart</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ path('product_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">show</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ path('product_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">edit</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

        <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('product_new') }}">
                Create a new entry
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    {% endblock %}
```

Product Entity:

```
namespace Pas\ShopTestBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Pas\ShopTestBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Description", mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $descriptions;
```

Description Entity:

```
namespace Pas\ShopTestBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collection\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Description
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="descriptions")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Pas\ShopTestBundle\Entity\DescriptionRepository")
 */
class Description
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     */
    private $productDescription;

    /**
     * @var Product
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="descriptions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $product;
```

Any help is really appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: So there can be multiple descriptions for a single product, yes?  That's what you're trying to display?

Comment: Yes, there could be. As it stands now each product has only one description so only that description will display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are way over-complicating the situation.  When you retrieve all of your product entities, you don't need to do anything else other than return those entities in your response.  Each entity already has its descriptions associated to it in your class definition.  Also, in a typical index action you do not necessarily need to throw an exception if no products exist...you probably still want to show the user the index page, and then if there aren't any products they will just see an empty table.  Your `indexAction()` can simply be:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('PasShopTestBundle:Product')->findAll();

    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    );
}
```

Your Twig is also going to cause problems the instant a single product has more than one description, because the number of `<td>` cells is going to be variable per row.  It would be better to do something like display a comma-separated list of descriptions, or perhaps separated by a `<br>` or `<p>`, or you could even make them an unordered list via `<ul>` and `<li>`:

```
{% for entity in entities %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ path('product_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.id }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ entity.price }}</td>
        <td>{{ entity.quantity }}</td>

        {% for description in entity.descriptions %}
            {{ description.productDescription }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {# ... #}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

That example gives a comma-separated list of descriptions, but you could change that loop however you see fit.  Also, you can add a `__toString()` method to your `Description` entity to avoid having to call that `productDescription` field directly:

```
// class Description
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getProductDescription();
}
```

Which would then allow you to do the following for your Twig:

```
{% for description in entity.descriptions %}
    {{ description }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice! Your solution however give me this error: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Pascal\ShopTestBundle\Entity\Description could not be converted to string") in src/Pascal/ShopTestBundle/Resources/views/Product/index.html.twig at line 26. (line 26 being where the second description is) Would I be wrong to say that description must be an array and not a string?

Comment: What is the name of the field on your `Description` entity that you want to display?  You will either need to reference that directly (`description.name` or whatever), or add a `__toString()` method on `Description` that returns that value.  If you update your Description entity with this field I can update my answer.

Comment: I got it, thank you again. You helped me understand this much more

Comment: No problem - what was the name of the field on your Description entity that was used to display the text?

Comment: I use: {{ description.productDesciption }}

Comment: Okay I will edit your post to include that field in your `Description` entity and update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I use another answer to put a formatted code.

If you has all products, and the relationship is correct, you just use them in loop.

```
foreach ($entities as $entity) {
   // To get the descriptions...
   $entity->getDescriptions();
}
```

By the way your code is very, very strange. First you are retrieving all products, after this, in a loop with this products, you are retrieving each product again and getting their descriptions. What you didn't care is:

**In your controller:**

`$entities` is storing all products.

`$entity` always will be the last product, it are defined in loop

`$descriptions` always will be from the last product

Now you send these variables to your view.

**In your view:**

You are doing a loop with the `entities` and declaring them as `entity`, this override the `entity` you passed in controller. By the way pass `$entity` and `$descriptions` to view is unnecessary, you are doing the loop with `entities`, just get these info in loop.

Comment: In View you are correct: I previously had {% for key, description in descriptions %} and used the description variable. I just fixed it to that now as well. As far as retrieving the products twice, I do this because I needed a way to get the individual product, hence $entity instead of $entities.

Comment: Ok, but in $entities you are putting in a loop right? In this loop you have individual product at each pass.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are working with an unitialized object, try to set the fetch level.

In your Product Entity you must to set a fetch level from relationship.

Fixing you relationship:

```
namespace Pas\ShopTestBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Pas\ShopTestBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Description", mappedBy="product", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $descriptions;
```

Comment: Still get the error: Error: Call to a member function getDescriptions() on a non-object

Comment: By reading the error: *Error: Call to a member function getDescriptions() on a non-object.* I supose that the object seems to be not found.

Comment: I see also a strange part in your code. You are retrieving all products and in result loop retrieving it again on database?

Comment: true, however it should not be the case. I have been trying to figure out why it is null as it is being used correctly (so I think) find($key) makes the objects null because $key is 0....again, so I think.

Comment: Yes I retrieve all products, the loop is for finding the correct description with those products

Comment: That does get descriptions but only for the most recent post in descriptions (it outputs the same description for each product). I had this solution before, which is why I started using $key in foreach

Comment: Try this: comment your return content at lines: `'descriptions' => $descriptions` and `'entity' => $entity`. Also comment all block that makes the loop, let just the `$entities = $em->getRepository('PasShopTestBundle:Product')->findAll();` and pass it to the view.